# Dart: How to parse Map variable with various special characters like $, {}, " and ' inside var

Tags: json, flutter, dictionary, parsing

I have map like this: `{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}`
As You see, inside code is a lot of `"", $, '' {}`. How I can parse it? I could not save this string as map, there is some my tries:

```dart
  Map m = {"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"};
  String s1 = r'{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}';
  String s2 = '{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}';
  String s3 = b'{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}';
```

But none of these line can not pass compilation.

Comment: The first version would be fine if you either escaped the `$` characters (e.g. `"{\$WWWWWW}"`) or used raw strings (e.g. `r"{$WWWWWW}"`).

Comment: ok, but how I can do it without modify any part of this char list: `{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}`

Comment: Why can't you prefix the strings with `r` to treat them as raw strings?

Comment: because I have a lot of `'` inside this string, so my raw value will have end in middle of string (before substring `TEXT` as You see)

Comment: Huh?  What does having `'` within the strings have to do with being able to use raw strings?  Why can't you do: `var m = {"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": r"{$WWWWWW}", "c": r"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}`?

Comment: This `m` variable is only sample of my code to clarify his case, real `m` variable have over 30k characters and have various combination of `' $ {} "` inside. It is hard to add  manually 'r' or '\' at long text. Now I found workaround for my problem - I load `m` variable from text file and convert to map using `Map r = jsonDecode(s);`. But I'm still interested in the other solution for this problem.

Comment: What other solution?  If you have a JSON string, then using `jsonDecode` would be the right thing to do.  If it's not a JSON string, then what is it?  Where did it come from?  Your question is very unclear.

Comment: I try solution which I use in Python a lot of years ago and... it works! Answer below

Comment: In response to your comment @jamesdlin : This map come from http request. I do not have problem with parse them. But I need to mock it, and save body of http response as string or map inside `.dart` file, and here is beginning of my problem. Now I solve it, thank You very much for comments, this discussion help me to find solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When string started with `r` and is surrounded by `'''` every special characters inside is ignored:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  String s = r'''{"a": "2022-01-26T17:10:51", "b": "{$WWWWWW}", "c":"$$$.id=='TEXT'"}''';
  Map r = jsonDecode(s);
  
  for(var i in r.keys)
  {
    print(r[i]);
  }
}
```

output:
[image]